# Replace quote (‘NOA’) using groovy

Tags: java, groovy

Can anyone guide me on how to replace this char (‘ ’) using groovy or java?
When I try the below code (i assume this is a single quote), it's not working.

```
def a =  "‘NOA’,’CTF’,’CLM’"
def rep = a.replaceAll("\'","")
```

My expected Output : NOA,CTF,CLM

Comment: What output are you expecting?

Comment: @tgdavies Thanks I've added my expected output in the description section.

Answer (score 1):

Those are *curly* quotes in your source text. Your `replaceAll` is replacing *straight* quotes.

You should have copy-pasted the characters from your source.

```java
System.out.println(
    "‘NOA’,’CTF’,’CLM’"
    .replaceAll( "‘" , "" )
    .replaceAll( "’" , "" )
);
```

See this [code run live at OneCompiler](https://onecompiler.com/java/3y9nd5dw9).

> NOA,CTF,CLM

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest this

```
a.replaceAll("[‘’]", "")
```

or even better to escape unicode characters in a source code

```
a.replaceAll("[\u2018\u2019]", "")
```